# NSMutableArray returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am writing a simple program that, I display a number from array 1 on a label and then move the number to array 2. However, the array keeps returning empty.

Here's my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self firstArrayInit];
    [self secondArrayInit];
    [self tranferA1toA2];



}

-(NSMutableArray *) firstArrayInit{
    self.originalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        [self.originalArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }

    return self.originalArray;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)secondArrayInit{
    self.secondArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    return self.secondArray;
}

-(void) tranferA1toA2{


    self.mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayNumber)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

}

-(NSMutableArray *)addToSecondArray:(int)myNumber{
    [self.secondArray addObject:[self.originalArray objectAtIndex:myNumber]];

    return self.secondArray;
}


-(void) displayNumber{
    static int num=0;
    if (num < level){
        myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.originalArray objectAtIndex:num]];
        [self addToSecondArray:num];

    }

    else{
        [self.mytimer invalidate];
        [myLabel setText:@""];
    }
    num++;


}
```

I've tried printing out the values in array 2 from `displayNumber` and it works. But, outside the function the array is empty.

Comment: what's level variable? where is it declared? what value is it assigned?

Comment: where do you call `addToSecondArray` method?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov in displayNumber method

Comment: @AndreyChernukha , it is just an integer set to 4.

Comment: @user2771150 then addToSecondArray method must be called. You wrote "outside the function the array is empty." when do you check it? and where? it seems like you're checking before the array is populated or even another object

Comment: It seems to be everything ok. Just do better debugging.

Comment: @user2771150 the piece of code you've adduced should work ok. The problem is somewhere else. I'm sure the problem is where you're checking

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I tried checking right after 'transferA1toA2' in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @user2771150 well. we found the source of problem. transferA1toA2 just schedules a timer which will be fired for the first time just two seconds later after you've checked. So your code is ok. You just check too early. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: ok, yes, that makes sense. Where do you suggest I check?

Comment: after the timer is invalidated of course. probably here  else{
        [self.mytimer invalidate];
        [myLabel setText:@""];
    }

Comment: Obviously… thanks @AndreyChernukha..  I've been coding all day. I think I need a break.

Comment: Also, Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @user2771150 made it an answer. Go get some rest, buddy, stop working

Comment: @user2771150 you said you would accept my answer, remember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as it is supposed to. The problem is that you check the array too early, even before the timer is fired for the first time. Check the array after the timer is invalidated